# Accidentally hit PIT during Odin update now phone is stuck

Tags: updates, odin

I was attempting to flash a handset using Odin, and accidentally clicked on the button marked `PIT`, and now the Odin is saying similar to this message - '*connecting phone ------ pc*'.

Also, the handset cannot be rebooted nor put into downloading mode.

Please advise?

Comment: mind sharing your phone model?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seem to have 2 options:

1. If under warranty, send it to service center, your Main board (PBA) should be replaced.
2. You probably will need a JTag repair!

AFAIK, there is nothing you can do at the moment, by yourself to get the phone working, apart from the options mentioned above!